# hosts file keeps reverting

Tags: networking, htc-desire-hd

I run `adb shell` and append a line to `/etc/hosts`
using

```
echo IP DNSName >> hosts
```

It works for a some time and then reverts back to having only a single entry for localhost.

Any idea what could cause this?
I am using temp root using VISIONary and I am connecting my HTC Desire HD adbd via WiFi, because it refuses to identify my handset via USB.

Answer (score 2):

No idea why it's doing it, but you could stop it by changing the permissions on the host file to read-only.

To set a file to read-only, log in as root via ADB (or use the Terminal application and log in as root) and then enter:

`chmod 444 <path-to-hosts-file>`

If you need to edit it again later on, enter:

`chmod 644 <path-to-hosts-file>`

Comment: I think you mean read-only. That should work as long as what's overwriting the file isn't an app that uses root, or the system itself doing it on boot.

Comment: Yes, that IS what I meant. DURRR. Thanks, I corrected it.  If the perms are set to ro, nothing should be able to overwrite it unless it also can set file privs, which is unlikely.

Comment: how do I set the file to read only?
Anyway, its not on reboot.

could it be a result of my "force close"ing an app and clearing its cache ?

Comment: Updated answer with more details on perms.  Also, it would be most unlikely to be from force closing an app unless it's an ad blocker.

Comment: No adblocker is involved. Nor does this help. It just keeps reverting even after I call `chmod 444 hosts`. Can I somehow log access to this file?